# How to access frames of RTCVideoRenderer ? (ios)

Tags: c++, ios, c, objective-c, webrtc

I try to access frames of RTCVideoRenderer without success, can you help me please ?

I noticed that there is a "didCaptureVideoFrame" method in RTCVideoCapturerDelegate, but not in RTCVideoViewDelegate.
I have never done objc, I added a method in RTCVideoViewDelegate to get frames (bellow "didChangeVideoSize"), but it do not get fired, I guess it do not work like that.

I am able to access frames from the remote using Android using the "onFrame" of VideoSink, I thought it would be that easy using ios.

PS: To add the method, I took the framework from the pod and put it in the project, because I noticed that when you modify a pod, changes do not apply.
Here is the line I added :

```
- (void)videoView:(id<RTCVideoRenderer>)videoView didRenderVideoFrame:(RTCVideoFrame *)frame;
```

I will now try to compile the library with the changes I want.

---

EDIT:

I am now compiling the library, I noticed the need to change several files to be able to access frames, it will not be done just by adding 10 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to this : [How to get frame data in AppRTC iOS app for video modifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134537/how-to-get-frame-data-in-apprtc-ios-app-for-video-modifications)

I used this line instead (because names changed since) :

```
@property(atomic, strong) RTCVideoFrame* videoFrame;
```

I wanted a "onFrame" like VideoSink on Android, but it will be ok for now.

Comment: I can't accept my answer until tomorrow, I do no think I will come back tomorrow

Comment: Were you able to do it "onFrame"?